# Quand utiliser « dehors » ou « au-dehors » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, adverbes, indications-de-lieu

Quand doit-on utiliser l'un plutôt que l'autre? Quelle est la différence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je crois qu'en terme de sens pur et en dehors des diverses locutions (dont *en dehors de*, justement) il n'y a pas vraiment de différences de sens: ce sont deux adverbes (d'accord, un adverbe et une locution adverbiale) signifiant « à l'extérieur ». E.g. le [TLFi définitions I.B. et III.B.1.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dehors)

Toutefois, je ne crois pas qu'il serait inexact de dire que *au-dehors* est archaïque dans la langue parlée standard, et au mieux soutenu ou littéraire à l'écrit.

---

I believe that in term of pure meaning and aside from expressions (i.e. *en dehors, mettre dehors*...), there is no appreciable difference in meaning, and both mean "outside". Cf. the [TLFi's definitions I.B. and III.B.1.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dehors)

However I don't think it would be inaccurate to say that *au-dehors* is archaic in the spoken language, and formal or literary in writing. If you do a quick search for it on Wikipedia, for example, you'll find many examples in citations rather than the running text of articles.

Answer (score 6):

D'après les définitions du petit Robert

> **dehors** : A l'extérieur, hors du lieu, de la chose dont il s'agit [extérieurement, ailleurs]
>
> Aller *dehors* : sortir,
>
> Coucher *dehors* :  soit dormir à la belle étoile, soit ne pas coucher chez soi.
>
> **au dehors** ou **au-dehors** : à l'extérieur [extérieurement, loin]
>
> - *au dehors* : à l'extérieur : Le récipient se brisa et le contenu se répandit *au dehors*
> - *au dehors* : dans l'apparence extérieure : « Homme auguste au dedans ferme au dehors, ayant En lui toute la gloire » (V.Hugo)

Bien que *extérieurement* figure dans les deux définitions,  il s'agit d'une externalité subjective (*dehors*, par rapport à moi) dans le premier cas et objective (*en dehors* de la scène ou de l'objet que je regarde) pour le second.

Toutefois certains parlés régionaux utilisent *au-dehors* pour *dehors*, surtout chez les anciens.